# Android Studio does not rearrange import in lexicographic order

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, import

Given the following imports

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment.*
```

Android Studio rearrange to the following when pressing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment.*
import javax.inject.Inject
```

Which is not in lexicographic order. My `pre-commit` hook running `ktlint` then fails because of this. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

The latest IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio might not be able to conform to full specifications in the [Android Kotlin style guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#import_statements). So, currently, there is **no straight-forward way** of arranging the imports lexicographic order in IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio.

For now, you may want to disable this check for Klint by [disabling 'import ordering'](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#editorconfig) in the ***.editorconfig*** file in the root of your project:

```
[*.{kt,kts}]
disabled_rules = import-ordering
```

This will disable the check in your project.

Answer (score 4):

Its strange behavior but if you delete all from *Import aliases separately* you will get *lexicographical order*

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio doesn't let you order imports alphabetically, neither in Java nor in Kotlin.
However Java features an *Import layout* section, which can give you some control. But still it's impossible to have an exact ordering, as you want it.

[image]

This **<s>isn't available for Kotlin</s>** is now available in Kotlin too. You can look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10974

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command on your android studio terminal. This will automatically reformat all the ktlint issues.
Cmd -

```
./gradlew ktlintFormat
```

Comment: This commend line works only if the project has ktlint implementation.

https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/install/integrations/

Answer (score 1):

You could disable import ordering for that file.

I had this:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.io.Serializable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

Ktlint reordered it that way, but check continued to fail:

Had to add the ignore in the first line:

```
import android.os.Parcelable // ktlint-disable import-ordering
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.io.Serializable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

Comment: I couldn't get this issue to be disabled universally, so I had to add this line to my file as well...thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in IntelliJ/Android Studio, usually just clicking Code -> Optimize Imports is enough to fix it

That’s just a linting error if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and I did manage to fix the issue by adding `// ktlint-disable import-ordering` but eventually I found a better solution.
If you have command line ktlint installed, you can run the `ktlint --android -F` terminal command on your android source code folder and it will automatically fix this issue. The `--android` part is very important, using the `ktlint -F` command, without the android part, will fix some ktlint issues but not his one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a rare case where my android project was using ktlint v0.47.1.  Everything passed when I ran the command `./gradlew ktlint` locally; and `./gradlew ktlintFormat` didn't find anything to change.

However, it kept failling the lint checks with the PR because it was using the latest version v0.48.2 in the Github action setup.  There are fixes for importing in v0.48.

I updated ktlint to v0.48.2 in the project in order to find and fix the lexicographic order issues.

Answer (score 0):

**2024 answer**

You can add this to your `.editorconfig`.

```
[*.{kt,kts}]
//your settings
ij_kotlin_imports_layout = *,java.**,javax.**,kotlin.**,^
```

It hides this type of errors if you don't need them.